# Not assignable property

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, properties, webrtc

So to resume my situation, I'm following a tutorial to try to understand WebRTC (https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-video-chat-app-from-scratch-webrtc-demystified-step-by-step-tutorial-p-2e74767c673). But I have made a little change by creating a component called `call-interface`, where I put everything about the main component (`app component`) inside. I did that because I wished to create a navbar where a link led to the call interface.

But I have the following errors:

```
Type '{ peerId: null; joinCall: true; } | { peerId: string; joinCall: false; }' is 
not assignable to type 'DialogData'.
Type '{ peerId: null; joinCall: true; }' is not assignable to type 'DialogData'.
Types of property 'peerId' are incompatible.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

Here are the useful parts from the code:

call-interface.component.ts

```
export class CallInterfaceComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private peerId: string;
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private callService: CallService) {
    this.peerId = this.callService.initPeer();
  };
  public showModal(joinCall: boolean): void {
    let dialogData : DialogData = joinCall ? ({ peerId: null, joinCall: true })        
                                           : ({ peerId: this.peerId, joinCall: false });
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CallModalComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: dialogData
    });
}
```

call-modal.component.ts

```
export class CallModalComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CallModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
  ) { }

export interface DialogData {
  peerId ?: string;
  joinCall: boolean
}
```

I tried to launch on VSCode the original version of the code and there were no problem, so I'm quite lost about what I did wrong to have a property problem. As such, I would like to ask some help please.

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to help me.

Comment: The error explains everything: `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.` and it talks about `peerId`. What are you not understanding about the error?

Comment: @AJT82 So I just need to replace null with empty string ( `DialogData = joinCall ? ({ peerId: null,....` with `DialogData = joinCall ? ({ peerId: '',....`) ? And what I don't understand about this error is why does it only appears on my code ?

Comment: Yes, instead of `null` you need to use either `undefined` or an empty string. Why it only appears in IDE... It's TypeScript, so TypeScript as the name indicates, checks types for you and warn you when you do something silly or wrong. It is there to help you during development. Debugging is much easier when the IDE can tell you where the type mismatch is.

Comment: @AJT82 Ok I understand now, thanks a lot!